# can I put comma behind and in the front of thus?

Tags: commas

"The longitude and Latitude  will be evaluated by the GPS**, thus,** displayed in the Google map as a marker with info box which contains the route number and the direction.   "

Comment: Why do you want ***thus*** in the first place? I think it would be more natural to just use ***and*** and forget about any commas.

Comment: @ocean: In your example sentence, the word *Latitude* should not be capitalized. Also, I believe it's customary to speak of "latitude and longitude" (in that order) rather than "longitude and latitude".

Comment: Do you mean ***then*** instead of ***thus***? I don't see which meaning of [*thus*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thus?searchDictCode=all) fits this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma only needed after GPS, and not necessary or preferred after 'thus.'